# analytical proof for a property of parabolas

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

$\overline{PQ}$ is a focal chord of the parabola with parametric equations $x=at^2, y=2at$. $\overline{PR}$ is another chord that meets the $x$-axis at point $(ka,0)$.

If the line $RQ$ intersects the $x$-axis at point T then we have the equality $\overline{TR} =k\cdot\overline{TQ}$.

Note.- This little-known metric property of parabolas was recently posted by new contributor lenaree. Unfortunately his post was closed.

Comment: So the original stays with this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4514014/question-related-to-chords-of-parabola

Comment: @Andrew D. Hwang.- Yes it is. I did not agree with the fact that the question has been closed. It was about a beginner who should be encouraged (it is my opinion and my collaboration in MSE is not for mathematicians but for beginners).

Answer (score 1):

The parabola has cartesian equation $y^2=4ax$. We have

$P=(at^2,2at)$, the focus is $F=(a,0)$, note the point $K=(ka,0)$.

Line $PQ: \dfrac{y}{x-a}=\dfrac{2t}{t^2-1}$ and
Line $PR: \dfrac{y}{x-ka}=\dfrac{2t}{t^2-k}$.

The point $Q$ is given by the system $$\begin{cases}\dfrac{y}{x-a}=\dfrac{2t}{t^2-1}\\y^2=4ax\end{cases}$$ whose solution other than $P$ is $Q=\left(\dfrac{a}{t^2},\dfrac{-2a}{t}\right)$

Similarly the point $R$ is given by the system $$\begin{cases}\dfrac{y}{x-ka}=\dfrac{2t}{t^2-k}\\y^2=4ax\end{cases}$$ from which $R=\left(\dfrac{ak^2}{t^2},\dfrac{-2ak}{t}\right)$

It follows the line $QR$ determines the point $T=\left(\dfrac{-ak}{t^2},0\right)$.

Finally $$\overline{RT}^2=\left(\dfrac{ak^2+ak}{t^2}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{2ak}{t}\right)^2\\\overline{QT}^2=\left(\dfrac{a+ak}{t^2}\right)^2+\left(\dfrac{2a}{t}\right)^2$$
We are done.